# Natural Number Game goals completed with error (invalid begin-end expression, comma expected)

Tags: integer, numbers, multiplication, lean, peano-numbers

When playing the Natural Number Game (in Lean), in [Advanced Multiplication World Level 2/4](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/natural_number_game/?world=9&level=2), I used the following code. The last three lines seem to cause trouble.

```
cases a at h,
left,
refl,
cases b at h,
right,
refl,
left,
rw mul_succ at h,
rw add_succ at h,

exfalso,
apply succ_ne_zero (succ a * b + a),
exact h,
```

This finishes with `no goals`, but with the error `invalid 'begin-end' expression, ',' expected`, and so the level doesn't complete. Rewriting the `apply` using `have p := succ_ne_zero _ h` yields the same error.

Of course, I can look up [a solution](https://github.com/adyavanapalli/natural-number-game-solutions/blob/master/advanced-multiplication-world/2) here, but what did I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a syntax error on the first line: `cases a at h` is not a valid input to the tactic. When you get the `invalid 'begin-end' expression` error the syntax is wrong so anything else it says is suspect.

You should use `cases a` instead; this already replaces `a` with `0` everywhere in the tactic state.

Comment: Oh yea the error messages do mention the two lines where I had `cases a at h` and `cases b at h`. Thank you.